# Converting rows to columns based on date to compare sales to promotions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a stored procedure that will compare sales data to promotions based on date. Currently I have all the data compiled however if there is more than one promotion on a single day the end results have multiple rows for a single date. I think I need to have one row per date to make the SSRS chart that is my end goal.

I've trued looking into the PIVOT function but I don't think that is quite what I need to make this work.

My current temp table results are as follows:

```
start_dt    promotion_channel   promotion_desc        promotion_cost
2019-02-07  Print               New Times 1/2 page    275.00
2019-02-16  Print               AZ Jewish Life        900.00
2019-03-07  Print               Scottsdale Progress   800.00
2019-02-18  TV                  PBS                   1200.00
2019-02-18  Radio               NPR - KJZZ and KBAQ   2626.00
2019-02-16  Online/Web          In house web campaign 1000.00
2019-02-18  Online/Web          kbaq.org              200.00
2019-02-16  Online/Web          AZ Jewish Life        1000.00
2019-02-16  Printed Collateral  Lightbox              137.00
```

My desired result would create one row per date with promotion_channel, promotion_desc, and promotion_cost columns being repeated as necessary.

Comment: Edit the question and show the results that you want to achieve.

Comment: If your end goal is just a chart, the chart would be able to SUM multiple costs and counts per date.